# Send Message using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms-gateway

I would like to send sms messages using C# code.
For that, I am using the 'clickatell sms Gateway'.
Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried searching something ?  http://www.clickatell.com/apis-scripts/scripts/c-scripts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their site, [C# Scripts](http://www.clickatell.com/apis-scripts/scripts/c-scripts/)

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
// Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a 
query.
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0
 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR
1.0.3705;)");
client.QueryString.Add("user", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("password", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("api_id", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("to", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("text", "This is an example message");
string baseurl ="http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg";
Stream data = client.OpenRead(baseurl);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
data.Close ();
reader.Close ();
return (s);
```

Comment: i useed this code it returns   ID: 7249d373e3acddffdc2b49cd1345c71c

Comment: Bear in mind that you need to sign up for an account with Clickatell first then get the API ID together with the user credentials

Comment: i have Tried this i have Register in the site...